# Hyphenated tags in chat should not be allowed to wrap

Tags: feature-request, tags, chat

When I use the `[tag:<tagname>]` syntax to link and highlight a hyphenated tag in chat, it is possible for it to break across multiple lines:

[image: broken tag]

It would be nice if the tag `[tag:cv-pls]` wasn't allowed to wrap.

Comment: Some tags can be quite long though...